# Username URLs that aren't case sensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I have an application where users set usernames, and their profile URL is matched to their username similar to Twitter. The issue I'm running into is case sensitivity. I'm down casing usernames before they save to the database, but I'm still getting the issue. Here's how I'm matching the URL's in routes

```
  match "/:id" => "users#show", via: :get
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you store it in the column called `username`.

In you Users Controller `show` action. You need to down case both the username column and the username from the params.

So you need to change:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

To be:

```
@user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["lower(username) = ?", params[:id].downcase])
```

---

For a cleaner approach you may change `params[:id]` to be `params[:username]` to avoid confusion.

Your route will be:

```
match "/:username" => "users#show", via: :get
```

Finding the user will be using `params[:username]`

```
@user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["lower(username) = ?", params[:username].downcase])
```

Comment: The other issue that arises is that usernames with numbers no longer work.

Comment: As this is not related. Describe your error in a new question, i will check it out.